# twilio Authenticate error even Account and Token are provided

Tags: c#, twilio

I have a .NET console app testing out some twilio methods.  The code to get a list of messages works simply enough.  The code to get the media associated with a message is throwing an authentication error.  I pretty much copied the code at

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/media#list

As soon as my code calls the MessageResource.Read(messageID) method, it throws an exception.

And yes, I'm calling:

```
TwilioClient.Init(SMS.AccountSID, SMS.AccountToken);
```

just before my call that looks like

```
            var mediaList = MessageResource.Read(twilioMessageSID);
            foreach (var media in mediaList)
            {}
```

Comment: What is the error that's being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the object you are referencing to get the Media is not correct, you are using

```
MessageResource
```

when it looks like you should be using

```
MediaResource
```

try changing your code to

```
var mediaList = MediaResource.Read(twilioMessageSID);
            foreach (var media in mediaList)
            {}
```